# Amazon RDS: Restore snapshot without backing up right after

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

Is there anyway to restore an Amazon RDS instance from a snapshot but skipping the backup step that happens right after it concludes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of this answer, unfortunately, there are nothing to avoid this first 'useless' backup.

Comment: how about a year+ later? I cannot seem to find otherwise.

Comment: How about 4 years later? Seems like we still can't skip this step.

Comment: I didn't check this recently so I don't know, but I think that no changes were made about this. :/